# How to implement owner check in Solidity

Tags: solidity, contract-design, keccak, ecrecover

Is there any EIP that specifies how to implement function in contract, that let's you call any other function as contract owner, with provided signature?

I don't want to reinvent wheel.

For example:

I want to create token contract, in which any address with ethers (for gas) can push transfer tokens transactions, as other address (sender) with its signature in which there may not be any ethers for gas.

```
  function transferFrom(address recipient, uint256 amount, uint8 _v, bytes32 _r, bytes32 _s) public {
    address recipient = msg.sender;
    bytes32 hash = keccak256('Transfer tokens:', recipient, amount);
    address caller = ecrecover(hash, _v, _r, _s);
...
  }
```

I need something like this.

My question is. Is there any EIP for that or maybe more generic EIP not only for token transfers?

Comment: I think you can use modifier for that.

Comment: Why would you need an EIP for a single state variable indicating who the owner is, and a simple check of whether or not the caller is also the owner??? BTW, you technically don't need `keccak` nor `ecrecover` here, so you as well remove those two from the tagging of this question.

Comment: I didn't explained my problem well. I edited post.
I know what `ecrecover` is and I am sure that contract needs that function, hash function also.

Answer (score 3):

```
contract Ownable {

  address public owner;

  modifier onlyOwner {
    require(msg.sender == owner, "Ownable: You are not the owner, Bye.");
    _;
  }

  constructor () public {
    owner = msg.sender;
  }
}

contract Owned is Ownable {

  function doSomething() public onlyOwner {
    // caller is the owner if they got this far.
    // carry on
  }
}
```

See the [`@OpenZeppelin/contracts access control contracts`](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/2.x/access-control) for a well-crafted implementation of this solution.

Hope it helps.

Edit:

- added Open Zepplin Link

Comment: It's not an EIP though, just a common implementation which has become a kind of "ad hoc standard".

Comment: BTW, OZ have changed `address public owner` to `internal` and later to `private` quite a long time ago (v2.0.0 if I remember correctly). The reason for it being that any inheriting contract (for example, contract `Owned` in your answer) has the permission to (undesirably) change the value of `owner` and damage the intended functionality of it.

Comment: That's true. My example is idiomatic. The OZ implementation addresses the subtleties that would take too long to explain.